# Why does a for comprehension expand to a `withFilter`

Tags: scala, for-comprehension, scalding

I'm working on a DSL for relational (SQL-like) operators. I have a `Rep[Table]` type with an `.apply: ((Symbol, ...)) => Obj` method that returns an object `Obj` which defines `.flatMap: T1 => T2` and `.map: T1 => T3` functions. As the type `Rep[Table]` does not know anything about the underlying table's schema, the `apply` method acts like a projection - projecting only the fields specified in the argument tuple (a lot like the [untyped scalding api](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference#map-functions)). Now type `T1` is a "tuple-like", its length constrained to the projection tuple's length by some shapeless magic, but otherwise the types of the tuple elements are decided by the api user, so code like

```
val a = loadTable(...)
val res = a(('x, 'y)).map { (t: Row2[Int, Int]) =>
  (1, t(0))
}
```

or

```
val res = a(('x, 'y)).map { (t: Row2[String, String]) =>
  (1, t(0))
}
```

works fine. Note that the type of the argument for the `map`/`flatMap` function must be specified explicitly. However, when I try to use it with a for comprehension

```
val a = loadTable(...)
val b = loadTable(...)
val c = loadTable(...)

val res = for {
  as: Row2[Int, Int] <- a(('ax, 'ay))
  bs: Row2[Int, Int] <- b(('bx, 'by))
  cs: Row2[Int, Int] <- c(('cx, 'cy))
} yield (as(0), as(1), bs(0), bs(1), cs(0), cs(1))
```

it **complains about the lack of a `withFilter` operator**. Adding an `.withFilter: T1 => Boolean` does not cut it - it then complains about "missing parameter type for expanded function", as `T1` is parameterised by some type. Only adding `.withFilter: Row[Int, Int] => Boolean` makes it work, but obviously is not what I want at all.

My questions are: why does the `withFilter` get called in the first place and how can I use it with my parameterised tuple-like type `T1`?

---

**Edit**
In the end I went with a `.withFilter: NothingLike => BoolLike` which is a noop for simple checks like `_.isInstanceOf[T1]` and a more restricted `.filter: T1 => BoolLike` to be used in general case.

Comment: I was always under the impression that `withFilter` is used on a monadic type in a for comprehension when you included a guard condition (like an `if` in the for comprehension) but I could be wrong.

Comment: That makes two of us

Comment: I believe your type annotation on the LHS is making it call withFilter to make sure the result is the right type

Comment: @Daenyth Yes, that is exactly what is happening. Unfortunately, the OP wanted this type to propagate into the `map` method so it does the right thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use for-comprehensions when you expect type inference based on the argument type of your lambda.

Actually, in your example, `as: Row2[Int, Int]` is interpreted as a pattern match:

```
val res = for {
  as: Row2[Int, Int] <- a(('ax, 'ay))
} yield (...)
```

Translates to something like:

```
a(('ax, 'ay)).withFilter(_.isInstanceOf[Row2[Int, Int]]).map(...)
```

Pattern matching in for comprehensions can be very useful:

```
val names = for {
  ("name", name) <- keyValPairs
} yield name
```

But the trade-off is, that you **cannot** explicitly specify the argument type of the lambda.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that's been revealing. So I could probably work around it with something like `withFilter(t: Any => Boolean)`, but then I get the "unchecked, type erasure" warnings, presumably from the `isInstanceOf` call? `withFilter(t: Nothing => Boolean)` works without a complain, but it seems like I could run into trouble when trying to extend it to actually do some useful stuff later...

Comment: Ahem... `withFilter(t: Nothing => Boolean)` is almost certainly not what you want. While you can call `withFilter` with any `Function1` that returns a `Boolean`, you cannot call that function inside the method (since there is no value of type `Nothing`).

Comment: To clarify a bit with what I ended up with: in my case the function is something which returns an abstract syntax tree instead of a concrete value, the signature is something more like `Rep[Nothing] => Rep[Boolean]` with covariant `Rep` type and the call works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into this issue also. Thanks to gzm0 explaining the Scala compilers behaviour I came up with this workaround:

```
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

object CatsNEL extends App {
  val nss: NonEmptyList[(Int, String)] = NonEmptyList.of((1,"a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c"))
  val ss: NonEmptyList[String] = for {
    tuple <- nss
    (n, s) = tuple
  } yield s
}
```